# Formula para calcular recargo equivalencia php

Tags: php

tengo que calcular el recargo de equivalencia con php y no consigo los valores correctos.

tengo este código:

```
$dcto0=$DLineasPedido["descuento"] / 100;
$importe=$DLineasPedido["precio"]*$DLineasPedido["cantidad"];
$dcto0=$importe*$dcto0;
$Baselinea=$importe-$dcto0;
$base = $base+$Baselinea;
$iva=$base*$DLineasPedido["iva"] / 100;
$Re=$iva*$Drecargo["Conf2"] / 100;
$Total = $base + $iva + $Re;
```

mirando esta [Pagina](http://infoautonomos.eleconomista.es/fiscalidad/recargo-de-equivalencia/), dice que si tengo 3000 y le sumo el 21% mas el 5,2% me debería dar 3786 pero a mi me da 3662.76 y el recargo de equivalencia son 32,76 cuando debería ser 156

¿que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final con la respuesta de Carmen ha quedado así y funciona.

```
$dcto0=$DLineasPedido["descuento"] / 100;
$importe=$DLineasPedido["precio"]*$DLineasPedido["cantidad"];
$dcto0=$importe*$dcto0;
$Baselinea=$importe-$dcto0;
$base = $base+$Baselinea;
$iva=$base*$DLineasPedido["iva"] / 100;
$Re=$base*$Drecargo["Conf2"] / 100;
$Total = $base + $iva + $Re;
```

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema conceptual, estás calculando el recargo sobre el IVA en lugar de sobre la base imponible, por eso no te sale correctamente.

Sería: 
3000 +(3000*0,21)+(3000*0,052)=3786

Acomoda tu PHP a esta operación y saldrá bien.

Comment: Perfecto, era eso :) Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda <3